# obtain value from string in column headers in R

Tags: r

I have a text file that looks like the following

```
DateTime               height0.1               height0.2
2009-01-01 00:00          1                     1
2009-01-02 00:00          2                     4
2009-01-03 00:00          10                    1
```

Obviously this is just an example and the actual file contains a lot more data i.e. contains about 100 column, and the header can have values in decimals. I can read the file into R with the following:

```
dat <- read.table(file,header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

where file is the path of the table. This creates a data.frame in the workspace called dat. I would now like to generate a variable from this data.frame called 'vars' which is an array made up of the numbers in the column headers (except from DateTime which is the first column).

for example, here I would have vars = 1,2

Basically I want to take the number that is in the string of the header and then store this in a separate variable. I realize that this will be extremely easy for some, but any advice would be great.

Comment: Like this? `my_var <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", names(dat)[2:3]))`

Comment: @Arun why don't you post as an answer?!

Comment: @SimonO101, in these questions, there's alway a "catch". See the comment to my answer.

Comment: @Arun I feel your pain! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the numbers you've are at the end of the names, for example, not like `h984mm19`, then, you can just remove everything except numbers and punctuations using `gsub` and convert it to `numeric` vector as follows:

```
# just give all names except the first column
my_var <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9[:punct:]]", "", names(dat)[-1]))
# [1] 0.1 0.2
```

Comment: what if the numbers are 0.1 and 0.2, I don't think this would work. And what if there are more than 3 columns in the data frame. Could you provide a more generic answer?

Comment: well, your question doesn't say anything about `0.1`. Edit your post to reflect the possibilities and I'll make an edit then.

Comment: @user1155751 that's why giving specific requirements in your question is a good idea...

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I'm used to matlab and not R, matlab users tend to develop generic codes not just for specific examples.

Comment: Could you share your generic solution in Matlab? You can not design a generic code to "all" string/regexp problems. There has to be "rules" for designing a regexp pattern.

Comment: +1 for the answer, wish I could give another for the patience